# Why does changing the order of semaphores matter in the Producer/Consumer Problem?

Tags: algorithm, debugging, concurrency, semaphore, producer-consumer

So I know how to code the Producer/Consumer problem, but I do not know why it works and why rearranging the code makes it not work.

```
int sizeOfBuffer = 1000;
sem_t full;
sem_t empty;
sem_t sem;
std::vector<int> buffer;
sem_init(full, 1, 0);
sem_init(empty, 1, sizeOfBuffer);
sem_init(sem, 1, 1); 
void producer()
{
    While (true) {
        sem_wait(empty);
        sem_wait(sem);
        buffer->push_back(1);    // add to the buffer
        sem_post(sem);
        sem_post(full);
    }
}
void consumer()
{
    While (true) {
        sem_wait(full);
        sem_wait(sem);
        buffer->pop_back;        // take away from the buffer
        sem_post(sem);
        sem_post(empty);
    }
}
```

So the code above works. No deadlocks and runs pretty fast even though I am using a std::vector buffer instead of an array buffer. The critical parts of memory is the buffer and it is protected by the semaphore called sem.

However, the code below does not work. The only change is the order of the execution of sem_wait() and sem_post(). But this leads to a deadlock and I just do not understand why. The critical section should still be similar but with empty and full semaphores now being critical as well as the std::vector.

```
int sizeOfBuffer = 1000;
sem_t full;
sem_t empty;
sem_t sem;
std::vector<int> buffer;
sem_init(full, 1, 0);
sem_init(empty, 1, sizeOfBuffer);
sem_init(sem, 1, 1);  
void producer()
{
    While (true) {
        sem_wait(sem);
        sem_wait(empty);
        buffer->push_back(1);    // add to the buffer
        sem_post(full);
        sem_post(sem);
    }
}
void consumer()
{
    While (true) {
        sem_wait(sem);
        sem_wait(full);
        buffer->pop_back;        // take away from the buffer
        sem_post(empty);
        sem_post(sem);
    }
}
```

So why does the order of the semaphores matter and why does the second code not work?
I think I need someone to explain this to me like I am five, because my friend tried to explain this to me and I only sort of understood that there is a difference, with one of them leading to a deadlock while the other one works perfectly fine.

Comment: In short: In the second case a producer locks `sem` and waits on `empty`, and a consumer waits on `sem`. And no one can make a progress. This differs from the first case, when a producer waits on `empty` but do NOT lock `sem`, so a consumer could make a progress after `sem_wait(sem);`.

Comment: You might want to study petri nets and try to re-create the petri nets for both codes. I once wrote some interactive petrinet app, which allows to input and then play with the nets. I used that whenever I wanted to make sure my concurrent programs work as expected. I am sure, someone else also wrote a petrinet simulator which is publicly available.